# How to "browser back" when using pushState?

Tags: javascript, pushstate

I have this code:

```
window.history.pushState(newUrl, "", newUrl);
```

My question is, how to make sure that when doing pushState the browser back button will function as normal or in other words should go "back"?

(without using jQUery)

Comment: What do you mean? why wouldn't it function as normal? or do you mean you want to use [replaceState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_replaceState()_method) ?

Comment: No I mean when user press the back button it does not go back to the previous page

Comment: @xybrek why does it not go back if user presses the browser back button? Is your browser defect?

Comment: @Black — Because they are using pushState!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The normal behaviour for the back button is for the browser to go back to the previous document, but when you use `pushState`, there *isn't* a previous document.

The point of `pushState` is to keep the browser on the *same* document while updating the URL. This is accompanied by DOM changes applied with JavaScript.

It is a **simulation** of going to a new page.

To make the back button appear to work, you need to write a matching simulation of going to the previous page.

You can do this by listening for [a `popstate` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate).

```
Page <span id="p">1</span>

<button>Next</button>

<script>
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function () {
  document.getElementById('p').textContent++;
  history.pushState({}, "", "/" + document.getElementById('p').textContent);
});

addEventListener("popstate", function (e) {
  document.getElementById('p').textContent--;
  e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

push is for pushing... adding

---

you should go for `history.back()`

If you want to popState - emit `popstate` event on window or do `history.replaceState()`

---

If you want to cancell commented event:
My answer will do the trick
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44553087/5694206

Comment: No I mean when user press the back button it does not go back to the previous page